Failed to create session factory: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
when running a project there is a runtime exception. Failed to create session factory: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister this is the error
i want to know why is that error occur and how to solve it

You need to provide more info for people to be able to help. What project? Which file in the project are you running? Which programming language are you using? Show us some code!
